# Vba hide pie chart slice

Tags: excel, vba, pie-chart

I have some Pie charts created using a macro. I need to change the macro so that it hides certain slices of the pie charts - this is easy enough to do manually by going to 'select chart data' and unticking the points you wish to hide. However I can't figure out which objects and properties that translates to in vba, and I can't go doing this manually every time this report is run.
*NB the simpler method of editing the base data that the chart is looking at isn't an option.*

Below is a code snippet I've been trying, which I will copy into the main macro once it's working. I think I'm pretty close, narrowing down to the specific point object I want to hide. Any help completing the last step will be much appreciated, as I can't figure what property to change to accomplish this.

```
Sub HideDataPoints()
'Finding out how to hide a slice from a pie chart
Dim sht As Worksheet, chtobj As ChartObject
Set sht = ActiveSheet
With sht
For Each chtobj In .ChartObjects
    If chtobj.Chart.ChartTitle.Caption Like "*Task*" Then
        With chtobj.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
            For a = 1 To .Points.Count
                If .Points(a).HasDataLabel = False Then
                ElseIf .Points(a).DataLabel.Caption Like "*Markham*" Then
                    'Point identified - how do I hide this slice from the chart?
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you want something like `chtobj.Chart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(a).IsFiltered = True` but you need to loop backwards through the points.

Comment: @Rory that's perfect, thanks for that!!